# Merging over csv files with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to combine multiple csv files into one csv file. The csv file are all in same format with 2 columns: 
1.date are all with in the same period (1/12/2014-31/12/2019)
2.Adj Close (the column that I wanna combine with, like in the following format)

```
Excel file 1:

Date            Adj Close
1/12/2014       100
.....
31/12/2019      101

Excel file 2:

Date            Adj Close
1/12/2014       200
.....
31/12/2019      201

expected output:

Date            Adj Close    Adj Close
1/12/2014       100          200
.....
31/12/2019      101          201
```

Following is the current code I have:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
def concatenate(indir = "C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\Stock Data",
                outfile = "C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\Stock Data\\combinedata.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    filelist = glob.glob("*.csv")
    dflist = []
    for filename in filelist:
        print(filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename,header= None)
        dflist.append(df)
    concatDf = pd.concat(dflist,axis = 1)
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile,index=None)
```

The output of current code is:

```
Date            Adj Close    Date          Adj Close
1/12/2014       100          1/12/2014     200
.....           ...          .....         ...
31/12/2019      101          31/12/2019    201
```

how can I get my expected output with over 200 files to combine? Thanks

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you can use pandas merge to get the desired result. Use Date column as an argument for "on" and perform outer merge. It will be helpful if you can add some examples to work with

Comment: hi i just wonder if I have 200 files how do i do a pandas merge loop?

Comment: Just iter your dflist and do a df.merge. But the column names will have suffix (a lot of them).

Answer (score 1):

The argument `axis=1` refers to row-wise concatenation (horizontal direction). Default is `axis=0` which is vertical.

If you want to join them on the same index, use [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

Comment: yes i figured it out but how could i do with the extra Date column from combined list?